# Rspec controller RoutingError

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I have the following routes defined

```
  match '/admin', :to => "admin/dashboard#index", :module => "admin"
  match '/admin/sales', :to => "admin/dashboard#sales", :module => "admin"
```

In the dashboard_controller_spec I am doping the following:

```
describe Admin::DashboardController do
  describe "#sales" do
    it "should set schedule" do
      get :sales
      assigns(:schedule).should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"sales", :controller=>"admin/dashboard"}
```

Any ideas?
My guess is has something to do with the module.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**Please note you have a typo in *assigns* (you have *assings*).**

I've been able to replicate this exact spec succesfully (Rails 3).

The dashboard_controller.rb file must be inside `app/controllers/admin/`
This is my quick test:

```
class Admin::DashboardController < ApplicationController
  def sales
    @schedule = "test"
    render :nothing => true 
  end
end
```

And results:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/dashboard_controller_spec.rb 
creating sqlite in memory database

Admin::DashboardController
  #sales
    should set schedule

Finished in 1.25 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: thanks for signaling the typo,but it was failing before it got there

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a Rails engine gem for my company which provides an API for the applications we're running.  We're using Rails 3.0.9 still, with latest Rspec-Rails (2.10.1). I was having a similar issue where I had defined routes like so:

```
match '/companyname/api_name' => 'CompanyName/ApiName/ControllerName#apimethod'
```

I was getting a similar error like:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
 No route matches {:controller=>"company_name/api_name/controller_name", :action=>"apimethod"}
```

I spent a great deal of time trying to figure out how to get my test to work. Different versions of Rspec, redefining my route using nested scopes, etc.

It turns out I just needed to redefine my route in underscore case so that RSpec could match it.

```
match '/companyname/api_name' => 'company_name/api_name/controller_name#apimethod'
```

I guess Rspec controller tests use a reverse lookup based on underscore case, whereas Rails will setup and interpret the route if you define it in camelcase or underscore case.